# Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;

Tags: html, wordpress, youtube

estoy intentando adjuntar a mi web un simple iframe sacado de youtube.
El tema es que (trabajo con wordpress), lo haga desde el codigo o lo haga a travez de custom fields con un editor, o directo en un post me da el siguiente problema.

```
Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.
```

Alguien sabe de que manera puedo solventar este problema?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Debes añadir el código que tienes y el valor que intentas pasarle al campo y que genera el problema. Seguramente incluye un carácter considerado peligroso (p.e. `<` o `>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene nada que ver con tu sitio, es un bug de Google Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807304

Para que desaparezca alcanza con actualizar a la última versión. A partir de la 66.0.3336.0 está corregido.

Edit: Corrijo, la versión 66 de Chrome todavía está Canary. Cuando salga va a dejar de aparecer.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la info, habia estado un poco malo y no habia podido responder antes